# Center the text of an inline-block

Tags: html, css

I need to center the text in one of my inline-block button. How might I go about accomplishing this? Any help will be appreciated.

Source Code:

CSS:

```
.dropMenu
{
    color: #FFFFF0;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: center;
}

.dropMenu:hover,
.dropMenu.selected
{
    background-color: #544E4F;
}
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class='dropMenu'><input type="image" src="images/down.png" name="dropDown" width="23" height="23">dropMenu</a>
```

Without `vertical-align : middle`:

http://img140.imageshack.us/img140/7476/withoutt.png

With:

http://img834.imageshack.us/img834/904/withe.png

Comment: Try to avoid using vertical-align, it works differently with different browsers and will act unpredictably if you don't fully understand how it works.

Comment: Play around in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Zfdra/1/  - black background added so text is visible.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa: I wish SO would reject all html/js/css questions that didn't have a jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Zfdra/2/ Take this as an example ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just find the solution by adding a label and changing his css:

Button

```
<a href="#no-reload" id='dM1' class='dropMenuButton'><input type="image" src="images/down.png" name="dropDown" width="18" height="18"><label for="dropDown">Menu</label></a>
```

Css

```
label
{
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;   
    vertical-align:super ;
}

.dropMenuButton
{
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Verdana, Geneva, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 80%;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know for sure that your options are going to fit on one line per option, you can use the `line-height` property to set the height and the text will automatically be vertically centered.

Comment: @Sindar Are you sure 10px is enough? You´d have to set it to the height of the menu.

Comment: @Sindar, it might, if you ensure that you've got rid of all `padding` on the `input` *and* its parent `a` element.